# Ada: Re-exporting enum type values

Tags: ada

I have an ada package in the form of

```
package C is
   type Test is (Test_1, Test_2, Test_3);   
end C;
```

and another package in the form of

```
with C;
package B is
   subtype Test is C.Test;
end B;
```

and yet another in the form of

```
with B;
package A is
   subtype Test is B.Test;   
   Item: Test := Test_1;
end A;
```

Naively, I would expect that a subtype defined in B, which is later subtyped by A, would be able to access members of the original type. However, upon inspection, the members of C are not even visible in the scope of B. This can be fixed by adding `use c;`, this seems like a find solution to a degree, however to use it in A, you would have to add `with c; use c;` to every package that transitively depends on C. This could lead to confusion as it wouldn't be implicitly obvious that you should be using C.

I would like to be able to "rexport" these types, so that I can abstract layers of my program better.

Comment: Look into "use type" (probably "use type c.test") to make the type visible without exposing all of C.

Comment: @BrianDrummond My major concern is that its not obvious that C is a transitive dependency, furthermore, this would require me modifying many areas of code where I am trying to apply this, whereas if there were a typedef -ike functionality the refactoring would be largely transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to re-export the values, you can do this:

```vhdl
with C;
package B is
   subtype Test is C.Test;
   function Test_1 return Test is (C.Test_1);
   function Test_2 return Test is (C.Test_2);
   function Test_3 return Test is (C.Test_3); 
end B;
```

Unfortunately, you can't use named numbers since enumerations are not numeric types. You can make these functions normal constants instead, but conceptually, this would execute code at elaboration time (the compiler will probably optimize it away, but you can't use `pragma Preelaborate` anymore).

This allows you to access the literals in `A` using `B.Test_1` etc. This is also a proper abstraction as `A` will not depend on the literals defined in `C` anymore (you can rename the literals in `C` without affecting `A`, you do need to update `B` though to map the new names to the original ones).

Simply importing the literal names into the namespace of `A` is not an abstraction.

Answer (score 5):

If you change package A to

```
with B;
package A is
   subtype Test is B.Test;
   use all type Test;
   Item: Test := Test_1;
end A;
```

the code compiles. Not sure whether this will help.

This is an Ada 2012 feature; see [ARM 8.4(8)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-8-4.html#p8) and (8.1). `use all type` makes the primitive operations of the type visible (which includes enumeration literals).

Comment: That is so close, but still wouldn't allow for functionality similar to a typedef in other languages. I'm beginning to suspect that this functionality is not possible in ada, unfortunately. This truly does get very close to achieving my goals though.

Answer (score 1):

```
with B;
package A is
   type Test is new B.Test;   
   Item: Test := Test_1;
end A;
```

...and all is well!

Comment: Please add an explanation to how this answers the question

Comment: All is well if you want a different type. All is not well if you want the same type.

Comment: Sure. Finally, it depends on what the OP would like: a subtype, or new type where the users of package A can ignore package C.

Answer (score 1):

Ada has the concept of *visibility*, with a lot of rules that define when, where, and how things are visible. Understanding visibility is key to understanding Ada. One of the best discussions of visibility is in [*Ada Distilled*](https://www.adaic.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Ada-Distilled-24-January-2011-Ada-2005-Version.pdf). What you're encountering is a consequence of the visibility rules. This goes even further than enumeration literals:

```
package Pack is
   type Int is range -(2 ** 15) + 1 .. 2 ** 15 - 1;
end Pack;

with Pack;
procedure Proc is
   subtype Int is Pack.Int;
   -- None of the operators of Int ("+", "*", ...) are directly visible here
begin
   null;
end Proc;
```

Declarations in a package spec are only visible outside the package by using dotted notation, unless you explicitly make them directly visible elsewhere. `use` clauses are one way to make them visible; others are `renames` and, for enumeration literals, declaring constants of the type initialized using dotted notation.